# APR profit calculator

Tags: windows, gratis, android, finance, calculator

I have Googled and see plenty of calculators for calculating loan/mortgage APR.

I am looking for the reverse - I want to specify an amount saved or invested, the current value and how many years it took to reach that value and have calculator tell me what APR that represents.

Gratis, Windows or Android, Linux at a pinch.

Comment: What you want is a old fashioned "business calculator" - there are lots of apps/emulators for them, or online - check https://www.alerusrb.com/calculator/FinCalc3.html

Comment: Looks good ... but I am too dumb to use it :-( I don't know the formula. I just want to say that my luxury yacht was worth $2 million 20 years ago and is worth $6 million now, and have it tell me that it has appreciated at X per cent APR.